# Run a block of code after SSH connection Bash

Tags: bash, ssh

After I ssh to a server, how do I run a block of code from my script remotely? Not sure if its possible.

```
ssh "$server"    #SSH login
echo Connected to "$serverName"
exec < filelist.txt
while read updatedfile oldfile; do
    # echo updatedfile = $updatedfile #use for troubleshooting
    # echo oldfile = $oldfile   #use for troubleshooting
    if [[ ! $updatedfile =~ [^[:space:]] ]] ; then  #empty line exception
        continue # empty line exception
    fi
    if [[ ! $oldfile =~ [^[:space:]] ]] ; then  #empty line exception
    continue # empty line exception
    fi 
    echo Comparing $updatedfile with $oldfile
    if diff "$updatedfile" "$oldfile" >/dev/null ; then
        echo The files compared are the same. No changes were made.
    else
        echo The files compared are different.
        cp -f -v $oldfile /infanass/dev/admin/backup/`uname -n`_${oldfile##*/}_$(date +%F-%T)
        cp -f -v $updatedfile $oldfile 
    fi  
done
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [SSH commands via bash script](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4225652/ssh-commands-via-bash-script)

Comment: question also asked on [unix&linux](http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/83228/4667)

Comment: possible duplicate of [What's the Cleanest Way to SSH and Run Multiple Commands in Bash?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4412238/whats-the-cleanest-way-to-ssh-and-run-multiple-commands-in-bash)

Answer (score 2):

You do it by using a `here-document` (untested below). Keep in mind that you will have to escape variables defined on the ssh server.

```
ssh $server <<ENDSSH 
echo Connected to "$serverName"
exec < filelist.txt
while read updatedfile oldfile; do
#   echo updatedfile = $updatedfile #use for troubleshooting
#   echo oldfile = $oldfile   #use for troubleshooting
           if [[ ! $updatedfile =~ [^[:space:]] ]] ; then  #empty line exception
            continue # empty line exception
           fi
           if [[ ! $oldfile =~ [^[:space:]] ]] ; then  #empty line exception
            continue # empty line exception
           fi 
        echo Comparing $updatedfile with $oldfile
        if diff "$updatedfile" "$oldfile" >/dev/null ; then
            echo The files compared are the same. No changes were made.
        else
            echo The files compared are different.
            cp -f -v $oldfile /infanass/dev/admin/backup/`uname -n`_${oldfile##*/}_$(date +%F-%T)
            cp -f -v $updatedfile $oldfile 
        fi          
done
ENDSSH
```

Comment: I keep getting this error../test.bsh: line 3: syntax error at line 24: `<<' unmatched

It doesnt like the <<ENDSSH

Comment: @mkrouse Put the last `ENDSSH` on its own line and make sure there are no characters before or after it.

Comment: Have to be careful which variables should be expanded by the locally running shell versus which need to be escaped so they are expanded on the remote shell.

Comment: @glennjackman yeah i made mention of that in my post.  Thanks for the reminder :)